# knockout.js Uncaught error: Unable to parse bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, velocity

I am using a simple example from internet and it's not working and giving me parse errors.

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: selectedCategory is not defined;
Bindings value: text: selectedCategory knockout-2.1.0.min.js:49
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: books is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: books
```

This is my total code in a velocity template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$application.asset('/js/thirdparty/knockout-2.1.0.min.js')">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function viewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.books = ko.observableArray([
                { title: 'The Secret', author: 'Rhonda Byrne' },
                { title: 'The Power', author: 'Rhonda Byrne' },
                { title: 'The Magic', author: 'Rhonda Byrne' }
            ]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    </script>

</head>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: books">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: author"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf0yxbmp/. So look at the referenced file and make sure it hasn't been corrupted, perhaps get latest version, or copy it down again and retry.

Comment: Where is `selectedCategory` (in the error) coming from as that's not in the code you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspect to me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$application.asset('/js/thirdparty/knockout-2.1.0.min.js')">
</script>
```

Try adding a different URL to Knockout. Here is the same script tag, but it points to Knockout on the Cloudflare CDN (the same version number is referenced as well).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js">
</script>
```